# java Read file via UDP

Tags: java, udpclient

I have a UDP server reading images, both UDP and TCP.
The protocol format is:
length
ID
payload

When I try to read the payload or image itself, I can do it by using a FLAG, but this is not desirable. How can I stop reading the file in UDP (or know when there is no more data) and write into a file?
The commented code, but using a FLAG, I dont want to use a FLAG as other clients may connect and will just transfer the raw image file.

Thanks

```
while (true) {
       socket.receive(receivePacket);
      /* 
       if (receivePacket.getLength() <= 8) {
           cmd = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0,receivePacket.getLength());
           if (cmd.equals("END_FILE")) {
               System.out.println("UDP ServerThread() Command: " +  cmd);
               break;
           }
       }*/


       fos.write(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
   }
```

Comment: Can't you send an initial packet with the length when connecting?

Comment: UDP is not thought for applications like that. Better use TCP.

Comment: I do have the length of the file, in initial message, how can i use it to read from socket.receive.

Comment: You have to make sure you can handle lost, fragmented and out of order packets. You need to include a header of your own to determine this, and you can include a flag what says its the end of the file.